# How to import python file from a relative path

Tags: python

As shown in the image posted below, I am trying to import both of the python files AreaOfCoverageDetails and NDVITIFFDetails, but at run time I receive the error that is pointed to in the image.
please let me know why I am getting that error and how to fix it.

**image**:
[image]

Comment: You have no `__init__.py` in your package. Take a look at this description from Jetbrains. I'm relatively positive this is your issue: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/refactoring-convert.html

Comment: I think you have to do a relative path import from the location of the main file that you run, not form a module or another file that you have already imported in your main code, for instance, if you have a main.py at the root of your project, every relative path should start from there

Answer (score 0):

add an empty `__init__.py` file in the directory and start the import path from the entry point of your application (without all of the dots): `from awanti.AreaOfCoverageDetails import AreaOfCoverageDetails`

I typically put these `__init__.py` files in every directory. Works well for me no matter where my file is in the project directories.